# Inheritance guideline for a child class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Since in **C#**, we can only inherit from a single base class and implement multiple interfaces.

I see this normal pattern everywhere:-

`DerivedClass : BaseClass, IInterface1, IInterface2`

How should one decide what goes inside BaseClass and what things inside the interfaces?

Are there any guidelines for it?

Comment: Don't use inheritance from the beginning, feel free to keep every thing in one class, when you will have all required functionality implemented you will see whole picture and will be able to recognise patterns and will be able to decide what goes to base class, if needed, or what goes to interface.

Comment: My understanding and usage of interfaces changed fundamentaly, when I realized, that they are _not_ a way of a class saying "look what _I_ can do!", but rather they are a way of some _calling_ code to express "this is what I _need_ in order to work". So when I create a class, I rarely think about what all the cool features it _could_ have. I create a class, because a job needs to be done and I have no other class that can do it. And to do the job, there needs to be a definition of what is needed. That's the interface. A base class is then to consolidate common functionality in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to follow these rules:

1. **Base classes** contain common methods or properties that will be used by its children, this is mainly to avoid having duplicated code in each child class.
2. **Interfaces** contain the methods or properties that need to be used outside the context of those classes. *And depending on the case they will be implemented by the base class or by the child classes.*

So it can happen that you want to have a method or property in the base class AND in the interface, and sometimes you will want it to be only in the base class because it's only a *utility* for its children.

But like everything in design, there're no 100% correct answers, it really depends on the context and the meaning of each object.

Answer (score 1):

Implementations should go into the base class while declarations into the interfaces. There can be some exceptions e.g. if a declaration is strongly coupled with an implementation, then both can go into base class.
 ( with C# 8 interfaces can have default implementations, but this should not be misused in my opinion)